# checking current tab against a string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension is using a page action (only available on twitter.com) and i wish to make the icon visible (and functional at least empty for now) in the adress bar but i can't get it working. 
I used the [documentation sandwich sample](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/pageAction/pageaction_by_content.zip) and modified it so it looks like this:

contentscript.js:

```
// Called when the url of a tab changes.
if(chrome.tabs.query(active(true),function{
  // If the url is twitter
  ( {'url':'https://google.com/google-results-string'}
  if (chrome.tabs.query({'url':'*://twitter.com/*'} , function(tabs){console.log(tabs)}){
    // ... show the page action.
    //chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({}, function(response) {});
  }
};
// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

background.js

```
function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {
// Show the page action for the tab that the sender (content script)
// was on.
    chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);

// Return nothing to let the connection be cleaned up.
    sendResponse({});
};

// Listen for the content script to send a message to the background page.
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

I'm not sure why it's not working and i'm not sure how to use the chrome.tabs.query() url attribute and how to check it against * ://twitter.com/ * .

Comment: Your JavaScript syntax is invalid. Why did you add the jQuery tag? And `onRequest` is deprecated, use `chrome.extension.onMessage`/`sendMessage`, or even the newer `chrome.runtime.onMessage`/`sendMessage`.

Comment: I'm a beginner in chrome extensions. Thank you for noticing me about the tag i will remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked and used the `Page Action by Content` example, when you should have been looking at the [`Page Action by Url`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#0ebfdfeb5e765ff6e1e8cb0c882ae98d) example. All you need is something like this in your `background` page:

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (tab.url.indexOf('twitter.com') > -1) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
  }
};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

There is no need to use a `content script` if you just want to check the url.

Edit: If you only want to test against the current tab then you can do something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,info,tab){
  if(tab.active){
    if (tab.url.indexOf('twitter.com') > -1)
      chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
  }
});
```

Comment: I want to check the url for the "activation" of the page action and after that i need to inject some html in the page and do some stuff that requires a content script. But i will check the url evaluation syntax.

Comment: Does this checks for sub-pages of twitter.com too ?

Comment: @Edeph This will show the page action for any url that contains the string `twitter.com`

Comment: It seems i have another issue,i can't get past the query of active window :
`if (chrome.tabs.query({active: true})){
    if (tab.url.indexOf('twitter.com') > -1) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id); 
     }
};
`
what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: @Edeph you aren't using `chrome.tabs.query` correctly. Try looking at some examples on how to use it.

Comment: Trust me i search the web like crazy and just cant find how to test the code from your answer only against the current tab :( Please help me with this one.